# Is it possible to define custom types in java that work with primitives?

Tags: java, primitive-types

For example the following is syntactically correct code

```
Double number = 10.0;
```

Is it possible to define my own class such as Price

```
Price myPrice = 10.0;
```

Actually compiles ?

Comment: You have over 40 questions without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auto-boxing and auto-unboxing only works with primitives. The concept you are talking about is similar to C++ conversions. Unfortunately, there is no such thing in Java. The best you can do is

```
Price myPrice = new Price(10.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't define your own primitive types for numerical quantities.

Declaring `Price myPrice` means that the variable myPrice will be of type Price and will be used to as its instance.

You can have following valid.

Suppose you declare variable `myPrice` of type `Price`. Some instance variables can be accessed via that `myPrice` reference.

```
Price myPrice = new Price();
myPrice.value = 10.0;
myPrice.currency = "Dollar"; 
etc ....
```

Comment: @Joachim : value and currency are the instance variables of `Price` class. So they can be accessed via `myPrice` reference

Comment: but there's no ``myPrice = new Price();`` so line 2 will throw a NPE. That's what Joachim meant. EDIT: answered too late :-/

Comment: ^ Yes ... Oops. Missed that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend `Double` class, since it is final.

But you can extend `Number` class and implement `Comparable` interface - the way actual [Double class is created](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

Answer (score 0):

No. It's hard-wired into the language.

Only primitives may be instantiated without the `new` keyword, except `String`, which although not a primitive, may be assigned using primitive syntax. ie both `new String("foo")` and `"foo"` will do it (note though that these are not *exactly* the same).

Comment: Strictly speaking primitives can't be instantiated at all, they are not objects. Auto-boxing allows implicit creation of primitive wrapper objects in some cases, however.