# How to implement boxing and unboxing in my own class?

Tags: java, boxing

In Java there is no operator overriding like i C++ so I can't figure out how to implement a boxing/unboxing for my own class.

For example it's possibile to use boxing and unboxing with Integer or Float when we do somethings like this:

```
int myVar = new Integer(25);
```

But how can I implement something similar in my class MyObject? (in the case I want to wrap a primitive type myself).  Is there any code example?

Comment: not possible this way, instead you can have wrapper classes for such functionality.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464782/is-it-possible-to-define-custom-types-in-java-that-work-with-primitives

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to implement auto-boxing and auto-unboxing for a user-defined class.

You can of course provide named methods to do the job. However, you would have to call them explicitly every time you need to box or unbox something.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to implement automatic boxing and unboxing for your own class - auto(un)boxing is a language feature, implemented in the Java compiler.

Answer (score 2):

autoBoxing or unboxing is available only with primitive in java
like `Long` wrapper class for long

```
Integer for int
```

but user defiend not possible,

best you can do  constructor initialize like

```
Myclass m=new Myclass(100);
```